# Error in plm.fit(data, model = models[1L], effect = effect) : empty model

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, plm

Good Morning,
I am trying to generate a linear mixed model with a random effect by using `plm` package of R.
I'm working on a df which you can download by clicking [here](https://cdn.scribbr.com/wp-content/uploads//2020/02/heart.data_.zip) , and structured as follows:

```
> str(tab)
'data.frame':   498 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ biking       : num  30.8 65.13 1.96 44.8 69.43 ...
 $ smoking      : num  10.9 2.22 17.59 2.8 15.97 ...
 $ heart.disease: num  11.77 2.85 17.18 6.82 4.06 ...
```

When I try to build a linear model as follows

```
> lin_mod<-lm(heart.disease~smoking, data=tab)
```

it gives me a linear model with no error, but when I try to introduce a random effect with plm as follows

```
random<-plm(heart.disease ~ smoking, data=tab, model="random")
```

or

```
random<-plm(heart.disease ~ smoking+X, data=tab, model="random")
```

or

```
random<-plm(heart.disease ~ smoking+biking, data=tab, model="random")
```

it gives me this error:
**Error in plm.fit(data, model = models[1L], effect = effect) : empty model**

I have looked up but apparently I do not do any noteworthy error, but of course I am doing something wrong. Could you give me some tips?
thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can use plm as you don't have panel data

Comment: OK, I've looked up (starting from your comment) and I got it. Thank you